# MongoDB --dbpath giving access to old data

Tags: mongodb

I have mongo installed on my local machine. When I start the database by running `mongod` I got this error (that is fairly common, and this site has solutions to workarounds):

```
$ mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
2015-01-01T22:31:17.350-0600 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2835 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=hermes
2015-01-01T22:31:17.351-0600 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.4
2015-01-01T22:31:17.351-0600 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2015-01-01T22:31:17.351-0600 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin minimavericks.local 13.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.3.0: Tue Jun  3 21:27:35 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.110.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-01-01T22:31:17.351-0600 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-01-01T22:31:17.351-0600 [initandlisten] options: {}
2015-01-01T22:31:17.351-0600 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296 
*********************************************************************
 ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
*********************************************************************
, terminating
2015-01-01T22:31:17.351-0600 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2015-01-01T22:31:17.351-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-01-01T22:31:17.351-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-01-01T22:31:17.351-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-01-01T22:31:17.351-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-01-01T22:31:17.351-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2015-01-01T22:31:17.351-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2015-01-01T22:31:17.351-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-01-01T22:31:17.352-0600 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-01-01T22:31:17.355-0600 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

I created a directory in my development environment at `/my/curent/directory/data/db` and started mongo again with `$ mongod --dbpath /my/curent/directory/data/db`, this time producing:

```
2015-01-01T22:32:31.282-0600 [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "./data/db" } }
2015-01-01T22:32:31.319-0600 [initandlisten] journal dir=./data/db/journal
2015-01-01T22:32:31.320-0600 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015-01-01T22:32:31.383-0600 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile ./data/db/local.ns, filling with zeroes...
2015-01-01T22:32:31.383-0600 [FileAllocator] creating directory ./data/db/_tmp
2015-01-01T22:32:31.482-0600 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile ./data/db/local.ns, size: 16MB,  took 0.098 secs
2015-01-01T22:32:31.842-0600 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile ./data/db/local.0, filling with zeroes...
2015-01-01T22:32:32.756-0600 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile ./data/db/local.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.914 secs
2015-01-01T22:32:33.215-0600 [initandlisten] build index on: local.startup_log properties: { v: 1, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "local.startup_log" }
2015-01-01T22:32:33.216-0600 [initandlisten]     added index to empty collection
2015-01-01T22:32:33.216-0600 [initandlisten] command local.$cmd command: create { create: "startup_log", size: 10485760, capped: true } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  reslen:37 1852ms
2015-01-01T22:32:33.216-0600 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2015-01-01T22:33:31.402-0600 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:33 virt:2635
2015-01-01T22:33:31.402-0600 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):160
2015-01-01T22:33:31.402-0600 [clientcursormon]  connections:0
```

It's great. Using the mongo shell, I can access my collections that I was working with in this directory, but I can also see all of my other databases from weeks prior (when this directory did not exist) using `show dbs`. **What purpose does the `--dbpath` option serve if not to isolate where data is stored?** Is something weird happening here?

Comment: Do you access the old data via mongo shell?

Comment: Check the `--dbpath` directory. Are the old data files in there? MongoDB is not going to magically find the old data, so I think you are mistaken when you say the directory is new (or you are not pointing MongoDB at the directory you think you are).

Comment: The old data is visible through `mongo` shell, but my logging `mongod` is never showing any connections.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB requires a [data directory](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-dbpath) to store all data. MongoDB’s default data directory path is `\data\db`.

To use an alternate dbpath, specify the path in the configuration file (e.g. `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\mongod.cfg`) or on the command line with the [--dbpath](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath) option.

Read more about [MongoDB Installation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)

---

If you are using windows then create `data\db` folder under C drive.

If you are using your own directory for data then pass **full path** of the folder as --dbpath argument value.

Comment: Even though I've changed the directory from what is was before, it will still serve all data on the machine? This directory did not exist an hour ago, but now all data is available through this directory.

Comment: modify the mongod.cfg file

Answer (score -1):

If MongoDB’s default data directory path "\data\db" is correct but accessing old data means just check your Task Manager.
End all mongo command and restart your mongodb. I tried it, working well